# arranging xml converted from a datatable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have converted my DataTable into XML.

The current **xml** output is this..

```
<DocumentElement>\r\n <cardDetails>\r\n  <mid>123456789190</mid>\r\n  <cardnumber>1234</cardnumber>\r\n   <expmonth>01</expmonth>\r\n <expyear>2017</expyear>\r\n   <cvv>404</cvv>\r\n    <amount>3.54</amount>\r\n   <exptime>1/1/2017 11:03:38 AM</exptime>\r\n  <responsecode>0000</responsecode>\r\n </cardDetails>\r\n
```

I wanted my output to be like this..

```
<DocumentElement> 
<cardDetails> 
<mid>123456789190</mid>    
<cardnumber>123456789190</cardnumber>    
<expmonth>01</expmonth>    
<expyear>2017</expyear>   
<cvv>404</cvv>    
<amount>3.54</amount>    
<exptime>1/1/2017 11:03:38 AM</exptime>    
<responsecode>0000</responsecode>  
</cardDetails
```

Here's my code

```
DataTable table = getGenerate.generateCard(mid, passcode, amount, expmonth, expyear, expday, days, hrs, numberOfCards);

            string xmlString = string.Empty;
            using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                table.WriteXml(writer);
                xml = writer.ToString();
            }
        return xml;
```

So, any help ?

Comment: `\r\n` is just the return code that is not getting applied in your view of the xml. Take a look here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Comment: Have you tried to save to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on your use case, but you can do this to solve your case.

```
xml.Split( new [] {@"\r\n"} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

You can find working code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mpvPME)

Comment: Thanks for this but how will I get the output here?

Comment: @jeramay10 you can check working piece of code posted with answer.

Comment: foreach (var a in s.Split( new [] {@"\r\n"} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   {
    Console.WriteLine(a.Trim());
   }

I mean with that, how will I get the return output here?

Comment: What you are asking is formatting, usually formatting will be applied during output/display time. if you are looking to break return string down to multiple lines then change the return type to `string[]`.

Comment: this doesn't work. .I tried to remove the foreach and it still returned the same output https://dotnetfiddle.net/fMOQsk